# Consume application/json in REST services using Jersey in Osgi

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, jersey, osgi

I'm deploying some REST services in an Osgi bundle using Jersey. The services are notated like

```
@POST
@Path("/adduser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML+","+MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Message addUser(User user) {
 ...
}
```

The first problem I have is that the service doesn't accept both of the MIME types I put into the @Consumes notation but just the first one.

The second and worst is that receive the following exeception when I try to call to the services. I can @Consumes text/plain and I can @Produces application/xml for example but if I try to @Consumes an application/json or application/xml the server throw the exception.

The exception is throwed when I make the call with a wellformed json or xml using a REST client or an ajax call, if the service just receive text/plain or doesnt receive anything the response to the client is made correctly in xml so the serializer is working ok when I send POJO's but not receiving them.

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Ljava/lang/Object;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/XmlRootElementJaxbProvider, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller, have different Class objects for the type ject; used in the signature
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:353)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at es.upm.cedint.gateway.api.corssupport.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:164)
    at es.upm.cedint.gateway.api.corssupport.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:246)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at es.upm.cedint.gateway.api.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Ljava/lang/Object;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/XmlRootElementJaxbProvider, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller, have different Class objects for the type ject; used in the signature
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:979)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:344)
    ... 36 more

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Ljava/lang/Object;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/XmlRootElementJaxbProvider, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller, have different Class objects for the type ject; used in the signature
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.XmlRootElementJaxbProvider.readFrom(XmlRootElementJaxbProvider.java:140)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:181)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:988)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:833)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.get(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractHttpContextValueFactory.provide(AbstractHttpContextValueFactory.java:66)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:94)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:343)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:237)
        ... 45 more
```

Anyone have any idea of what could be wrong?

PD:I have @XMLRootElement at the begining of the User class that I want to serialize and the server I use is Jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, I do not think you should have one function with two different signatures. I mean if you want to accept json or XML those are two different functions although they look the same from the java point of view. In your case I would create these three functions:

```
@POST
@Path("/adduser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Message addUserXML(User user) {
 return addUserInternal(user);
}

@POST
@Path("/adduser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Message addUserJSon(User user) {
 return addUserInternal(user);
}

private Message addUserInternal(User user) {
  ...
}
```

As the second question: One of the worst thing that happened with Java 6 (in my opinion) is that they moved JAXB and other technologies into the JRE classpath. I guess you have also JAXB in one of your bundles. Jersey and the bundle that contains the REST API wire to different packages. One of them wires to the bundle that contains JAXB while the other wires to the boot classpath (package coming from JDK)

You can have two solutions (at least)

**First solution**

You exclude the JAXB packages from the boot classpath by configuring your OSGi environment.

**Second solution**

The packages coming from JDK have the version 0.0.0_jdkversion. The JAXB package coming from the bundle has a nicer and higher version like 2.1.1. You can edit the MANIFEST.MF of Jersey and your bundle to point to that version of the package.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help in both questions, it works nicely now!