# How REST API receive request body data?

Tags: java, rest, struts2, annotations

I am using an action in struts2 to post json to a REST API.

Now to post Jan object I do as following

1. use `JSONObject.fromObject(Object object).toString`,
2. then use `postmethod.setRequestEntity()`,
3. finally client excute post method

So how should  REST API  receive data ?

Here is code a segment :

```
@POST
    @Path("addUser")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String addUser() {

    };
```

Comment: Is it duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660487/consume-application-json-in-rest-services-using-jersey-in-osgi ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi No, this question is about Struts 2.

Comment: I think this guy have some problem receiving data, and he is using https://jersey.java.net to consume the rest api generate data. @Clarence please send more details

Comment: the question is if i send a Object(like User) not parameter(like name ) to rest api ,how   should i get user   .  I don't know clearly where the problem is.But it is probably the data type,meidatype...but finally i solved...thank you  ，anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access parameters in a RESTful POST method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194408/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-restful-post-method)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question as I think, to receive a JSON String in REST API, you can use a JAXB. You can refer the following.

REST API

```
@POST
@Path("addUser")
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String addUser(Student s) {
    //Your logic here
    return "user added";
};
```

JAXB representation for student.

```
public class Student {
    String id;

    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String age;

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(String id, String name, String age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student() {

    }
}
```

When you post Student JSON String, you will get the Raw Student object in addUser method. Correct me, if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: No,you are right.Actually the code i write is the same as you.but i can not receive data(user object) from client.so i  found a new way and i did it. Then i would put my new way and thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. First I add `@XmlRootElement(name="user")` to my model--user,
2. then in action i convert user to xml，of course you should set `Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XMl`
3. ```
   @POST
       @Path("addUser")
       @Produces("text/plain")
       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML)
       public String addUser(User user) {}
   ```
4. add

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```

to web.xml

finally you can get user.

Comment: @Pasupathi,the code above is my solution,thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the body part in back-end code using Rest API (JAX-WS-RS) with jersey and apache-cxf then you need to configure your rest package of classes like that..

```
  @Path("/student")  //path of rest package of class 
  @Consumes("application/json")  //If you want to consumed produced json
  @Produces("application/json") //If you want to produced json
  public class StudentRest{

     Student student=new Student();

     @GET
     @Path("returnstudent")
     public Student ReturnStudentMethod()
     {
            return student;
     }

     //if you want to receive or produced some specific type then write
     @GET
     @Produced("application/pdf")
     @Path("returnpdffile")
     public Response ReturnPdfFile()
     {
            return file;
     }
```

}

```
And also you need to set web.xml if you are using jaxrs with jersey
   <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
```